# uwp - Variablesizedwrapgrid Spacing in Gridview as ItemPanel

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to make a Tile wall just like what Zune (the music player made by MSFT) has. I'm following the guide from [Jerry Nixon's blog](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/08/windows-8-beauty-tip-using.html). I'm using a custom GridView inherit from GridView and Variablesizedwrapgrid and setting fix RowSpan and ColSpan of every items in the GridView to make them different. Here is how it looks like[image].

However, there is always some empty space left and no item occupy that.

Here is the code of the custom GridView:

```
public class MyGridView : GridView
{
    protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, object item)
    {
        try
        {
            dynamic _Item = item;
            element.SetValue(VariableSizedWrapGrid.ColumnSpanProperty, _Item.ColSpan);
            element.SetValue(VariableSizedWrapGrid.RowSpanProperty, _Item.RowSpan);
        }
        catch
        {
            element.SetValue(VariableSizedWrapGrid.ColumnSpanProperty, 1);
            element.SetValue(VariableSizedWrapGrid.RowSpanProperty, 1);
        }
        finally
        {
            base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);
        }
       
    }
}
```

This is the data structure of the item source of the GridView

```
public class Tile
{
    public BitmapImage Thumbnail { get; set; }

    public int index { get; set; }

    public object RowSpan { get; set; }

    public object ColSpan { get; set; }
}
```

So basically how it works is that for every Tile we have fix RowSpan and ColSpan set when we create the Tile object. They can be used when GridView is allocating the space for each item. Some tiles have RowSpan and ColSpan in 4 so that there is a 4x4 size tile and so on and so forth.

The reason why there is space left because we pre-defined the size of the container of each item by setting the RowSpan and ColSpan of each item before rendering the item. Since those numbers are fixed, the item will wrap to next Column if it is too large to fit in.

The most intuitive thought is making the following items move forward and occupied the empty cell but it doesn't seem working in GridView. Then I'm thinking making the item shrink once there is empty space created but it might require the parent container aware of it and tells its children that and it is beyond my knowledge.

It would be appreciated if anyone can give me an hint or a solution for this. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jason_wun, I have found the similar issue about auto arrange item in `GridView` in msdn. And **Diederik Krols** has given [acceptable answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/fb75f5e0-b9e7-4084-a604-8b5c445e0e27/variablesizedwrapgrid-spacing-in-gridview-as-itempanel?forum=wpdevelop) that you could refer to. The following is answer reference.

> You may want to use the FluidWrapPanel from [`CompositionProToolkit`](https://github.com/ratishphilip/CompositionProToolkit#2-fluidwrappanel) instead, or look at its source code to adjust your positioning algorithm.